# adapting 'future' to 'future_promise'

Tags: r, promise, future

I am trying to convert this to a `future_promise` for a few reasons (some of which are just curiosity, tbh), but I can't seem to do everything I'd like to do. Perhaps some of it is just misreading the docs, but I think there's something else I'm doing incorrectly than just misunderstanding the purpose/flow.

Using `future` alone, I can work with the future process fairly easily.

```r
library(future)
# library(logger)
plan(multicore, workers = 10)
(ppid <- Sys.getpid())
# [1] 2704731
quux <- future({
  logger::log_info(msg="in", ppid=ppid)
  Sys.sleep(3)
  out <- mtcars[sample(32, size=3),]
  logger::log_info(msg="out", ppid=ppid); out; }, seed=TRUE)
# {"time":"2022-11-12 14:13:43","level":"INFO","pid":3189217,"user":"r2","msg":"in","ppid":2704731}
quux$job$pid
# [1] 3189217
1+3   ### demo that the repl is still interactive
# [1] 4
# {"time":"2022-11-12 14:13:46","level":"INFO","pid":3189217,"user":"r2","msg":"out","ppid":2704731}
value(quux)
#                 mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt qsec vs am gear carb
# Merc 240D      24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.0  1  0    4    2
# Toyota Corolla 33.9   4  71.1  65 4.22 1.835 19.9  1  1    4    1
# Lotus Europa   30.4   4  95.1 113 3.77 1.513 16.9  1  1    5    2
```

However, I do not know how to:

1. Know the forked PID, formerly determined with `quux$job$pid` (useful for parent/current process tracking);
2. <s>Perform a `then` on the promised results, and have the `then` expression operate in the parent/current (not a child/forked) process</s> (solved with `%>%` instead of `%...>%`);  and
3. I am failing to get to the value itself.

```r
library(promises)
did_something <- FALSE
quux <- future_promise({
  logger::log_info(msg="in", ppid=ppid)
  Sys.sleep(3)
  out <- mtcars[sample(32, size=3),]
  out
}, seed=TRUE) %>%
  then(~ {
    logger::log_info(msg="out", ppid=ppid)
    did_something <<- TRUE
    .
  })
# >
# {"time":"2022-11-12 14:40:53","level":"INFO","pid":2704731,"user":"r2","msg":"out","ppid":2704731}
# >
quux$job$pid
# NULL
did_something
# [1] FALSE
quux
# <Promise [pending]>
# >
# {"time":"2022-11-12 14:40:53","level":"INFO","pid":2704731,"user":"r2","msg":"out","ppid":2704731}
quux
# <Promise [fulfilled: data.frame]>
did_something
# [1] TRUE
value(quux)
#  Error in UseMethod("value") :
#    no applicable method for 'value' applied to an object of class "promise"
```

Is that the canonical use of `future_promise` with `then`-clauses?

It's clear I'm missing something rather fundamental to `future+promises`.

(This is not intended to run in `shiny`, in case anyone thinks to bring in observers or reactivity.)

---

```r
sessionInfo()
# R version 4.1.3 (2022-03-10)
# Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
# Running under: Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
# Matrix products: default
# BLAS:   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openblas-pthread/libblas.so.3
# LAPACK: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openblas-pthread/libopenblasp-r0.3.20.so
# locale:
#  [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8
#  [4] LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8
#  [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                  LC_ADDRESS=C
# [10] LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C
# attached base packages:
# [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base
# other attached packages:
# [1] promises_1.2.0.1  future_1.29.0     data.table_1.14.2 dplyr_1.0.10      optparse_1.7.3
# loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
#  [1] Rcpp_1.0.9        later_1.3.0       pillar_1.8.1      compiler_4.1.3    tools_4.1.3
#  [6] odbc_1.3.3        digest_0.6.29     bit_4.0.4         jsonlite_1.8.0    lifecycle_1.0.1
# [11] tibble_3.1.8      pkgconfig_2.0.3   rlang_1.0.5       bench_1.1.2       DBI_1.1.3
# [16] cli_3.3.0         parallel_4.1.3    curl_4.3.2        yaml_2.3.5        fastmap_1.1.0
# [21] globals_0.16.1    generics_0.1.3    vctrs_0.4.1       fs_1.5.2          hms_1.1.2
# [26] RPushbullet_0.3.4 bit64_4.0.5       getopt_1.20.3     tidyselect_1.1.2  glue_1.6.2
# [31] listenv_0.8.0     R6_2.5.1          redux_1.1.3       processx_3.7.0    parallelly_1.32.1
# [36] fansi_1.0.3       profmem_0.6.0     callr_3.7.2       purrr_0.3.4       logger_0.2.2
# [41] blob_1.2.3        magrittr_2.0.3    codetools_0.2-18  ps_1.7.1          ellipsis_0.3.2
# [46] assertthat_0.2.1  config_0.3.1      arrow_10.0.0      utf8_1.2.2        crayon_1.5.1
```

Comment: As far as i know it si not possible to sync the value with the library functions, one should always use "then" and all methods (promise_all, etc.) return promises. https://github.com/RLesur/crrri/blob/aeea7d6fd0bba7b40cc51ff160ed90f96ca2dee6/R/hold.R#L34 here a solution to get the value of a promise synchronously. I saw another workaround in github but i do not remember right now where

Comment: Thanks @RicVillalba ... I find it interesting that while `promises` does not `Import: shiny`, the only portions I've seen of getting to the promised value is within a shiny observer/reactive-component.

Comment: 'course, I could always add `val <- NULL` before the pipe, and then `val <<- .` inside the `then` clause ... seems kludgy to be the preferred or only method.

Comment: As best as I understand, `value(` will only report something once all 'something' are resolved. And as this can  be both final values or futures, or both, there's something unresolved and `value(` is blocking. Interesting it can return an error...Revealing how little I know, I will merely follow to see how this develops. (an effect of logging?)library(promises) not promise

Comment: The thing is this: if it were not finished, then it _should_ block (based on the expected behavior of `value(.)`), but (1) `quux` alone returns `<Promise [fulfilled: data.frame]>`, suggesting that it is complete, and (2) it returned immediately, again suggesting it is complete. Yeah, I think `value` is intended solely for `future`s, not for `promise`s, so it's certainly a mis-projection of intended results. Thanks @Chris

Comment: `unclass(quux)` reveals some interesting conditions, beyond that quux is a lingering,fulfilled promise for which what to do with it hasn't been detailed in `then` (and what I would write is give me my `out`), but operations are further suspended by assignment to promise2, to allow evaluation of the various paths one could go upon success or reject. So, what `then`?, seems to be where we are, and success to this point.

Comment: I think you're wrong on [2], immediate return, as I understand it, is essentially saying, it'll be attended to (off line as it were), but don't let that hold us up from continuing on to even more interesting things, which is the `async`(probably best to say 'advantage', rather than promise).

Comment: My point about immediate return is that `value(.)` returned immediately. If the `then` were still executing (or waiting to execute) then that should have been blocking. But it didn't, so it was complete.

Answer (score 1):

1. I believe getting the in-proc PID is not supported.
2. (Already resolved, use `%>%` instead of `%...>%`.)
3. As long as `then(.)` does not return the value (nor make it available), I think the only way to get the value from a `future_promise` is side-effect from the `then` block. For instance,

   ```r
   quux <- NULL
   ign <- future_promise({
     logger::log_info(msg="in")
     Sys.sleep(3)
     out <- mtcars[sample(32, size=3),]
     out
   }, seed=TRUE) %>%
     then(~ {
       logger::log_info(msg="out")
       quux <<- .
     })
   quux
   # NULL
   #### pause
   quux
   # INFO [2023-01-16 15:09:50] {"msg":"out"}
   #                 mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt qsec vs am gear carb
   # Toyota Corolla 33.9   4  71.1  65 4.22 1.835 19.9  1  1    4    1
   # Merc 230       22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.9  1  0    4    2
   # Ferrari Dino   19.7   6 145.0 175 3.62 2.770 15.5  0  1    5    6
   ```

Comment: So, ultimately, what is desired here and what R 'wart' is being addressed in the more generalized uses of `future` and `promises`, as the resort to `<<- .` tossing it up to global almost seems an end around, as `<<-` generally seems an end around when present in a function environment. Feature or Bug? (and I really should read the code at some point...)

Comment: Using `<<-` is a kludge to work around that `then` returns a promise-object and not the value itself. Looking at `ign` here, there are _references_ to the `value`, but I can't seem to get it ... and frankly, since there are no easy accessors to get at it, it seems to me that they are not necessarily better than `<<-`, which is at least simpler to understand, explicit, and controllable. The scope-breach of `<<-` is controllable so long as we create `quux beforehand. @Chris

Comment: Are you making a `future_promise(` to accept your answer or awaiting further input?

Comment: Not sure how long I'll keep it open. Do you have any additional/opposing thoughts on it?

Comment: I've been looking, [using promises](https://appsilon.com/an-example-of-how-to-use-the-new-r-promises-package/), and have packageVersion('promises')
[1] ‘1.2.0.1’, but note the most recent (jan 21,22) commit is related to `future_promises`,  so  maybe we should be working with `git clone` of promises, and/or submit above there to see if feedback from devs can elucidate.