# How to use future::resolved with promises::future_promises

Tags: r

i'm trying to determine if a `future_promises` is fullified. In the `future` package one can use the `resolved` function to check whether a `future` is resolved or not, but i don't get how to use it with `promises`. `promises` seems to resolve immediately :

```
> future::plan(future::multisession)
> 
> f <- function() {
+   Sys.sleep(10)
+   return(TRUE)
+ }
> 
> x <- promises::future_promise({
+   f()
+ }) 
> 
> y <- future::future({
+   f()
+ }) 
> 
> future::resolved(x)
[1] TRUE
> future::resolved(y)
[1] FALSE
```

How to use `resolved()` with `promises` ? Or how do you check that a `promises` is resolved/fullified ?

Ideally i would like to do some operations while the `future_promises` is evaluating e.g. `while (!resolved(future)) Do Something`

Comment: Related (though not the same): https://stackoverflow.com/q/74413807/3358272

Comment: Realize that if you continually "do something", you'll never really know if the promise has resolved unless you allow the current (not future/forked) REPL to work a little bit: I call `later::run_now()` periodically to allow it to work on this, though admittedly I don't know for certain when it does something.

Comment: thanks for the link and the `later::run_now()`tip, i was trying something with this code `f <- function() {Sys.sleep(10);return(TRUE)};is_finished <- FALSE;x <- promises::future_promise({f()});x %>%then(function() {is_finished <<-TRUE});while(!is_finished) {print(is_finished);Sys.sleep(1L)}` but as you said it was impossible to determine if the promise has resolved, adding `later::run_now()` to the `while` solved the issue, thanks